# Is it possible to select all the element which is overflow a particular div and give it some CSS and place in some another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]I want to select all the element which is overflow a particular div and give it some CSS and place in some another div.

Like I have a div of height 400px and I am adding json data to it , if the content goes outside of this div I want to take all the outside content and place it to another div.

```
if(print_part.offsetHeight<print_part.scrollHeight)
{
    var body=document.getElementById("body");
    $("body").append(
        '<page size="A4" id="A4Page" style="margin-top:0px;!important"><div class="main_Header"><h5>AMERICAN UNIVERSITY OF ANTIGUA</h5></div></page>'


        );
}
```

Comment: You want to begin with [that](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then you look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction). Then the answer will come up to your mind.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have a fast way to do it. This could be improved by for now I have no time. This is the idea behind this.

```js
const e = document.getElementById('overflow');

if (e.scrollHeight - e.clientHeight > 0) {  
  const lineHeight = getLineHeight(e);
  
  let allLines = e.innerHTML.match(/[^\r\n]+/g);
  
  const linesToShow =  Math.trunc(e.clientHeight / lineHeight);
  
  const linesToMove = allLines.slice(linesToShow, allLines.length - 1);
  
  const originalDivContent = allLines.slice(0, linesToShow - 1);
  e.innerHTML = originalDivContent.join('\n');
  
  const containerDivContent = linesToMove.join('\n');
  const container = document.getElementById('container');
  container.innerHTML = containerDivContent;
  
}

function getLineHeight(element) {
  const clone = element.cloneNode();
  clone.innerHTML = '<br>';
  element.appendChild(clone);
  singleLineHeight = clone.offsetHeight;
  clone.innerHTML = '<br><br>';
  doubleLineHeight = clone.offsetHeight;
  element.removeChild(clone);
  return doubleLineHeight - singleLineHeight;
}
```

```css
.fix {  
  width: 200px;
  max-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="overflow" class="fix">
 aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
 aaaaaaaaaaaaa
 aaaaaaaaaa
 aaaaaaaaaaaaa
 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
 aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
 aaaaaaaaa
 aaaaaaaaa
 aaaaaa
 aaaaaaaaaaa
 aaaaaaaaa
 
</div>

<div id="container" class="container"></div>
```

Comment: What if the content is not like strings aaaa that you have given exmaple  but HTML tags like <p></p>,<table></table> and other tages

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that's not easy possible like you thought it.

You really have to take every of your content-items, find out their height. If parentSize < contentItemsTotal than put it to the other container.

Can you add some of your code, which you already have written?

Greetings